# user activity monitoring

Tags: monitoring, user, system-monitoring

I'm a sysadmin for a small network and want to monitor user activity. Is there a good/standard  software I can use? I'm not looking for keylogging but would like to see where they are spending most of their time.

Comment: Do you mean what they're doing on the web or in terms of applications running on the desktop?

Comment: both would be preferred... but primarily the web.